# Qt move constructor linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, c++11, linker

I'm trying to compile a project in Visual Studio 2010, with Qt 4.8.4.

When I build it, I obtain linker errors like following ones:

```
error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QByteArray & __thiscall QByteArray::operator=(class QByteArray &&)" (__imp_??4QByteArray@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z) not resolved
error LNK2001: external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: class QString & __thiscall QSTring::operator=(class QString &&)" (__imp_??QString@@QAEAAV0@$$QAV0@@Z) not resolved
```

You can see the move constructor in linker, but I'm not using any C++11 feature.

The linker error appears in files where I've code like this:

```
QByteArray xTmpArray;
QString    xString;
...
xTmpArray = xString.toAscii();
```

If I comment the assignment line, the link error disappears (same for QString assignment).

How can I eliminate these link errors?

Answer (score 3):

I've solved. It was (naturally) a linking problem, because they gave me libraries compiled with Visual Studio 2008, that does not support move constructor. I've used the correct version, compiled with VS2010, and all works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QByteArray>

int main() {
    QString s("a");
    QByteArray ba = s.toAscii();
    return 0;
}
```

I am compiling it with command:

```
g++ -I /usr/include/qt4/QtCore/ -I/usr/include/qt4/ qtuse.cpp -lQtCore -o qtuse
```

And I have no problem. Looks like you have forgotten to link your program with QtCore.

Check your project settings. You should add Qt's lib dir to link paths.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Visual Studio, not g++. The project seems correctly linked, and I have this problem since switching from 4.8.0 to 4.8.4 (because God of Project Leader decided that newer is better). I'm actually linking qtmain.lib, QtCore4.lib, QtGui4.lib.

Comment: Did you try to compile the above program?

Answer (score 0):

In `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015` go to:

```
(Project properties)->General->Platform Toolset
```

and set that to `visual studio 2013 (v120)`

This have worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when there is version mismatch between MSVC and pre-built Qt binaries. Don't do that.

If you're using MSVC2015 you need to link against the pre-build MSVC2015 Qt libraries.